# get all records from database that meet my needs with raw SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `courses` table and `teachers` table in MySQL database.

I would like to find all new courses that are not yet assigned to any recruited teacher of this year that age is younger than 30.

- The relationship is each course has many teachers. So, in `teachers` table, there is `course_id` column
- `teachers` table has a `year` column to indicate which year the `teacher` is recruited and an `age` column.

The SQL I tried:

```
SELECT courses.* from courses
        INNER JOIN teachers t ON t.course_id = courses.id
WHERE t.year = '2019' AND t.age<30
```

This gives actually all courses that have been assigned to teachers recruited this year and age is younger than 30, which is opposite than what I need.

I would like to filter the above by combine with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from teachers WHERE year=2019 that returns zero.
```

I am not sure how to do so. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And take a look at [mcve] before you start!

Comment: This one looks like homework?

Comment: How do you know what a "new course" is?

Answer (score 1):

Finishing the Zaynul's answer:

```
select courses.* 
from courses
  left join teachers t on t.course_id = courses.id and t.year = '2019' and t.age<30
where t.course_id is null
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/281ca0/1)

To further comment on the data structure, the year should be an integer and the course-teacher relation should be in it's own table, otherwise a teacher can only teach one course.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select course_id
from teachers 
where year = 2019 and age < 30
```

returns all the `course_id`s that you **don't** want in your results.
You can do a left join of `courses` to this query and get only the non matching rows:

```
select c.*
from courses c left join (
  select course_id
  from teachers  
  where year = 2019 and age < 30
) t on t.course_id = c.id
where t.course_id is null
```

or use `NOT IN`:

```
select * from courses 
where id not in (
  select course_id
  from teachers  
  where year = 2019 and age < 30
)
```

Another way with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select c.* from courses c 
where not exists (
  select 1 from teachers t
  where t.course_id = c.id and t.year = 2019 and t.age < 30
)
```

Answer (score -1):

try using left join

```
SELECT courses.* from courses
        left JOIN teachers t ON t.course_id = courses.id
WHERE t.year = '2019' AND t.age<30
and t.course_id is null
```

Comment: You should move the conditions in the `where`-clause into the `ON` in the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @slaakso, why do u think so??

Comment: welcome to put down vote but it will help if you tell the reason of downvote

Comment: Did not downvote as the basic idea of the answer was corrent. Just that the "t.year = '2019' AND t.age<30" part of the where-clause should be in the ON-part, otherwise the left JOIN turns into normal join.